# Regex to match file name

Tags: regex, date, datetime, time

I am struggling with a certain regex. I need it to match the following pattern :
`cmpx-yyyymmdd-hhmm`. I have tried multiple solutions from the internet like the following :

```
cmpx.((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9]).*
```

Nothing works and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing works how? In what environment? With what string?

Comment: your pattern dont have slashes, but your regex is

Comment: This, and the regex itself incorrectly contains double backslashes (`\\d` should be `\d` *for purposes of the regex*). In a language without verbatim strings or regex literals (Java, for example), it *may* be necessary to double them, but usually you shouldn't. That's why @stribizhev asked about the environment you're using.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Actually, there were single slashes before Andrea's edit, and I believe OP used single slashes. The question is rather unclear without sample input, explanation of what went wrong and the programming language it is used in.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be vastly overcomplicating it, or you have  not explained the question properly.

Try: `cmpx-\d{8}-\d{4}`

If you cannot use `\d` try `[0-9]` in its place.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of detail. We are using Intellij environment in XML camel DSL. We are trying to identify files with in a folder that contain the following : cmpx-yyyymmdd-hhmm and transfer them to another folder. So far this is what we have tried :<camel:from uri="file://D:/In?include=cmpx-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}" />

Comment: That regex looks like it should work but I'm afraid I don't know the ins and outs of Inteillij/Camel DSL.